# ERROR: Running application failed - Spring boot + Boxfuse/AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cloudcaptain

I am trying to run my Spring boot application on AWS using boxfuse.
I have followed the [following](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cloud-deployment.html) tutorial from Spring (section 54.4) and the [Get Started](https://console.cloudcaptain.sh/#/getStarted) from Boxfuse aswell.

When i run the following command

```
boxfuse run target\digigram-0.1.0.jar -env=prod
```

i get the following lines

```
Waiting for AWS to boot Instance i-74fe7fc8 and Payload to start at http://52.28.94.159:8080/ ...
WARNING: Healthcheck (http://52.28.94.159:8080/) returned 404 instead of 200. Retrying for the next 120 seconds ...
Terminating instance i-74fe7fc8 ...
```

And it ends with

```
Destroying Security Group sg-0ed6f667 ...
ERROR: Deployment of pantera160/digigram:0.0.0.1453900589995 failed in prod:Payload of Instance i-74fe7fc8 came up at http://52.28.94.159:8080/
with HTTP 404 (expected 200) => ensure your application responds with an HTTP 200 at http://52.28.94.159:8080/ or adjust the healthcheck configuration (healthcheck.path, healthcheck.timeout, ...) to fit your application
ERROR: Running pantera160/digigram:0.0.0.1453900589995 failed!
```

I don't understand where the problem lies. Do I have to change something in AWS or in my application or...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE:
I am running on a free plan for AWS, might this be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxfuse ensures that a correct version of your app stays up and running and does not get replaced by a bad one. Only when a new version does pass Boxfuse's health check, does Boxfuse reassign it the application's Elastic IP. Once that is complete Boxfuse terminates the instance of the old version.

To verify that a new version of your app comes up correctly Boxfuse expects the new version's instance's healthcheck path to return HTTP 200.

The default healthcheck path for a regular Spring Boot application without the actuator is `/`. Your app currently answers 404 there instead of 200.

You have a number of options to fix this:

- Add a controller to your app mapped to `/` that returns HTTP 200 when your app comes up correctly.
- Change Boxfuse's `healthcheck.path` to a different path that does indeed answer HTTP 200 when your app comes up correctly.
- Disable Boxfuse's health checks by setting `healthcheck` to `false` (not recommended as this effectively prevents Boxfuse from checking whether your application came up correctly)

Pick either one of these options and your app will come up correctly as you would expect.